# Undefined variable when using Cisco IOS facts on Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm using cisco.ios.ios_facts in Ansible to get IOS facts on Cisco devices:

```yaml
- name: Cisco Get Facts
  hosts: routers, switches
  gather_facts: false
  connection: network_cli

  tasks:
    - name: Gather only the config and default facts
      cisco.ios.ios_facts:
       gather_subset:
        - config
      register: output

    - name: print output
      debug:
        var: output.stdout_lines
```

I'm receiving the following error:

```
TASK [print output] ************************************************************
ok: [router1] => {
    "output.stdout_lines": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
ok: [router2] => {
    "output.stdout_lines": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
ok: [switch1] => {
    "output.stdout_lines": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
ok: [switch2] => {
    "output.stdout_lines": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
ok: [switch3] => {
    "output.stdout_lines": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

I have the output variable in my previous task, but the print output task cannot identify that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I seriously doubt that `ios_facts` returns a `stdout_lines` key in its result. What do you see if you debug the bare `output` registered var? And what happens if you try to debug any of the [documented returned values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cisco/ios/ios_facts_module.html#return-values)? Those should actually be available in as subkeys of the `ansible_facts` key for every hosts in your play.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see what's going on there.

```yaml
- name: Gather only the config and default facts
  cisco.ios.ios_facts:
    gather_subset:
      - config
  register: cisco_output

- name: print output
  debug:
    var: cisco_output
```

The `cisco_output` should show the output on the console. See if 'stdout_lines' is defined. If not, it could most likely be 'stdout'.

Comment: `ensure the first task has a status 'changed'. If that is not happening, the variable will never register.` <= this is actually not true. The variable will be registered in whatever situation. Meanwhile, if the task status is `skipped` or `failed`, the key `stdout_lines` might actually not exist. And it might not exist at all in all cases in the result from a module which job is to gather specific facts from a remote device.

Comment: Ah right. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, it works without stdout_lines